# Scoped strictNullCheck rule in Typescript

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I have a big project where `strictNullCheck` was not used from the beginning and I cannot just turn it on in compiler options without very big refactor. I have my part of application also where I would like to have this rule turned on. Is it possible to have it enabled only there without including the rest of the project? Unfortunatelly when I just add tsconfig in my library with rule enabled, it includes all the dependencies, also from the rest part of the project :/

Comment: Given [ms/TS#31035](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31035) I don't think this is possible, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it is possible to do following the such way:

```js
// folder structure 

- src/
  - tsconfig.json
  - index.ts
  - utils/
    - tsconfig.json
    - helper.ts
    
    
// utils/tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strictNullChecks": true
  }
}
```

Comment: as I said, it wont work if helper includes something from src

Answer (score 0):

In typescript you can't specify different compilation options for different parts of a project. However, you could achieve something close to this with ESLint and this plugin: https://github.com/JaroslawPokropinski/eslint-plugin-strict-null-checks

With ESLint you can have rules that apply to only parts of the project, by using the `override` property or by including an `.eslintignore` file.

Comment: I tried it, but this plugin has bugs with simplest use cases like https://pastebin.com/5T5wE8sJ

Comment: Good observation ... saw that you filed an issue, hope there is a way forward